# Aggregate roots and repository in DDD

Tags: domain-driven-design, ddd-repositories, aggregateroot

I just started on DDD and encounter the term aggregate roots.

My current understanding is that this is kind of a parent entity that hold reference to other complementary entity. Example : aggregate roots will be Employee that also contain position, shift, gender, and salary.
My first question will be whether this understanding is correct ?

Secondly, I get an impression that repository is defined only for each aggregate. Yet, it puzzles me how we could retrieve information regarding other entity (Ex: list of positions or shift type) ?

Thank you,

Comment: For a complete tutorial including a modelling example and coding, you can also read my [DDD Decoded: Aggregate](http://blog.sapiensworks.com/post/2016/07/14/DDD-Aggregate-Decoded-1) trilogy.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike, definitely will check your page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aggregates are consistency boundaries to enforce invariants. This means that the entities and objects inside the aggregate must remain consistent together with regards to the business rules.

- http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/
- http://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html
- https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2015/05/25/ddd-the-aggregate/

> Secondly, I get an impression that repository is defined only for each aggregate. Yet, it is puzzle me how we could retrieve information regarding other entity (Ex : list of positions or shift type) ?

You can have a separate read model over your data if you choose to do so and it makes sense that the business wants to view the data in a different way. The consistencies you need to enforce when you are writing data do not apply on the read side. [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) is the pattern to help with this - you separate your write side from your read side.

https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2015/04/07/cqrs-revisited

Comment: Is the business rule the synonym of invariant? You use it that way, but somebody wrote that they are different...